# jQuery BlockUI not firing after several synchronous calls

Tags: jquery, jquery-blockui

I'm trying to use the [jQuery BlockUI Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#page) but I'm running into trouble. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:
... On the click of a button
 
1) Initiate the blockUI call:

```
$.blockUI({ message: '<h1 class="label"> Just a moment...</h1>' });
```

2) Call a function

```
function (someArray){
  for(x in someArray){
    //Make an ajax call based on x
  }
}
```

3) After 2 is complete, initiate the unblockUI call: `$.unblockUI;`

What I'm noticing is that the ajax calls are firing first, and then the $.blockUI is being run. And then $.unblockUI is never called. To be clear, I'm making multiple ajax calls to the server, depending on the size of someArray.

How would I structure this code? I'm only beginning to learn Jscript, JQuery, ajax and so on. I've looked up callbacks, promises, etc. I'm not sure what I'm doing or what to research anymore...

Thanks!

```js
function trigger() {
  startblock(callAjax);

}

function startblock(callback) {
  $.blockUI({
    message: '<h1 class="label"> Just a moment...</h1>'
  });
  callback(endblock);
}

function callAjax(callback) {
  $("#myParagraph").innerHTML('mimic a series of ajax calls')
  callback();
}

function endblock() {
  $.unblockUI;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js/"></script>


<button type="button" class="button" id="btnCreate" onclick="trigger()">Create</button>

<p id='myParagraph'>
```

Comment: With the available code , I am not able to figure out what is wrong. I would suggest you to post some more code so that other developers can find out what is wrong

Comment: Maybe put together a working jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry guys, it's my first time posting here - and suffering from a learning curve.
I tried to put together a code snippert but even after referencing jquery.blockUI.js and the jquery library, I'm still getting an error that it doesn't know what '$'

Please let me know if this it helps?